# Manage MultiType objects under a single structure

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting, data-management

I'm trying a datamanager framework in C++ which would periodically (when Manager::checkout() is called) save the current state. This would be the base of a system allowing application to restart after a system error.

The idea would be to have a singleton class called Manager which would hold all the variables in it, the user could just simply create a new managed variable by doing

```
int& i = Manager::get().make<int>("variable_id");
double& e = Manager::get().make<double>("other_variable_id");
```

My issue is on how to manage the variable from the manager point of view.

My first idea was to build an object class templated by the variable type which would hold the variable as well as methods for serialization / management of the variable.

Still if I had a lot of those

```
Object<char>, Object<double>, Object<std::vector<int>>
```

All casted to

```
Object<void>
```

And store in a

```
std::map<std::string, Object<void>>
```

I would not know how to interact with those objects (as the Manager would not know the underlying type). I cannot store the type as an element of the Object (sadly types are not objects in C++) and I don't want to use enums in order not to impose limitations on what can and cannot be stored other than just the serialization part.

Any idea how I could do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that "a singleton data manager" sounds like an awful idea ("data manager" is probably the worst name for a class I could **ever** imagine), the kind of type erasure you want is heavily based on one important condition:

#### Do I know all of the types beforehand?

- If you do know, use `variant` (Boost has an implementation) and the proposed visitor pattern.
- If you don't, take a look at `any`.

Either way, the basic idea is that you annotate the type-erased pointer with a *value* denoting its *runtime type*. C++ does that (and we call that RTTI), but in your case it's probably better to do that by hand.

Comment: Thanks, any looks like the thing I'm looking for, I'll look more deeply into it